# Compile SFML with /MT flag in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction, windows-runtime, sfml

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and I want to compile my graphics application, which uses the SFML framework, with the `/MT` compiler flag instead of the Visual Studio default `/MD`. This can be set up in the project settings at `Configuration -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library`. The mentioned flag controls whether to dynamically (`/MD`) or statically (`/MT`) link the Windows runtime library.

Changing just this settings in the project file of my own application results in linker errors because the value of `RuntimeLibrary` is set to `MD_DynamicRelease` in SFML but it is `MT_StaticRelease` in my project. Therefore I need to compile SFML with the /MT flag. I created the Visual Studio project file using CMake but in the project settings there are much less settings. The point is that there isn't even a category `Configuration -> C/C++`.

So how can I find the options page or set the `/MT` flag manually?

(By the way the names of the options pages might not be perfectly correct since I translated them from the German version of Visual Studio I sadly use.)

Comment: The SFML CMake scripts should already offer an option to link the runtime libs statically (SFML_USE_STATIC_STD_LIBS).

Comment: You will only get "less settings" when you don't have the project selected in the Solution Explorer window but, say, a source file.  Be sure to right-click the *project* and choose Properties.  /MD was selected in SFML for a Good Reason btw.  You really should build a static library and not a DLL when you build with /MT.  Although you probably get away with it in VS2012.

Comment: @HansPassant. There are fewer settings available, I have opened the project settings. Anyway I am interested what the good reason for SFML to use /MD is. I want my application to be built as executable.

Comment: @AndreiTita. Thanks, I used the CMake option and it worked. If you would write a short answer I will mark that as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CMake scripts provided with SFML come with an option to link the runtime libraries statically (SFML_USE_STATIC_STD_LIBS).